# Search in YII2 by foreign key value?

Tags: php, yii2-advanced-app

I have two tables

```
1.users(id,name),
2.user_products(id,user_id,products)
```

In yii2, how to customise the search on `user_products(user_id)` field by the `users(name)` value in grid view search.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Data searching by related attributes is shown on the yii2 website:

[Displaying, Sorting and Filtering](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview/)

**tldr;**

You have to create the relation between both models and add the virtual property you want to search by to your rules of the search model.